# Do filepaths need to be English

Tags: php

I'm trying to verify a directory exists with PHP:

```
is_dir('C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Среда чтения')
```

But the result is always false. Do I have to name a directory in English for PHP to correctly work with them?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is English only:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Downvoting the question because it wasn't in English is lame.

Comment: @Irwin - but downvoting a question because it doesn't fit the rules isn't lame. And English is in the rules. A question that almost nobody can understand is about as useful as spam.

Answer (score 4):

try to use utf-8 in your script
also check slashes

Comment: Lol, mkay. If you can understand the post, consider also translating it :D

Comment: @pst I believe that some would call his response "sarcasm"

Comment: @ColinMorelli Really? It seems like a perfectly valid answer to "Why does `is_dir(..)` return false?" - but I don't know Russian (?), so the question might be entirely different.

Comment: @user2014288 - See my answer. If it's Linux, then you need to know what encoding the filename is in (might not be UTF-8). If it's Windows, then you need to use Windows-1252 (and remember the setting about Non-Unicode programs).

Answer (score 2):

### On windows

The filesystem is always UCS-2, unfortunately PHP is not so smart. I'm not really sure if the `is_dir()` reduces to an ANSI API call or WideString, but it would make sense to go with ANSI. In that case you're at the mercy of the "Language for Non-Unicode programs" OS setting. Filenames in the wrong languages will be inaccessible for you.

### On Linux

It's not so straightforward. The filesystem itself doesn't really have a certain text encoding, which makes things awkward. A Cyrillic  filename can be stored in UTF-8 or Windows-1252 (or whatever else), and it's up to the software that creates/reads the files to recognize what the encoding was. The filesystem just stores a bunch of bytes as the "filename". PHP also doesn't care about text encodings either, so you really need to know what the encoding of the filename is beforehand, so that you can pass the correct string to `is_dir()`.

### In summary

I highly recommend steering clear of non-English characters in filenames when using PHP. It's damn hard to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if `file_exists()`:

```
if(file_exists('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wednesday read'))
{
    // Do your thing...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a specific example, you can look at the problem the other way around:

### What dirs exist

```
$dirs = scandir('C:\Users');
print_r($dirs);
```

Since you know there is a folder named "Администратор" - see how php displays it. By  taking the result that php receives, you can hopefully determine the correct encoding to the specific folder. If the encoding is consistent (which according to [Vilx-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541281/761202) it is) it should be possible to handle any folders/files with cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Administrator rights!

Use UTF-8.

Use linux, at least in VM. It will save you a lot of time.

You should NEVER rely on non-ASCII paths!

Use file_exists() function to test if file/directory exists: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused because you didn't 'escape' the backslashes, therefore, PHP tries to do this:

```
is_dir('C:UsersАдминистраторDesktopСреда чтения')
```

Which doesn't work.

Try escaping your back-slashes;

```
is_dir('C:\\Users\\Администратор\\Desktop\\Среда чтения')
```

Although using 'slashes' also works on PHP on windows;

```
is_dir('C:/Users/Администратор/Desktop/Среда чтения')
```